# Where to download SONY Imaging Edge for MacOS 10.12

Tags: software, sony, remote, sony-a7ii

Where can I find a downloadable version of Sony Imaging Edge (Remote/Viewer/Edit) compatible with MacOS 10.12?

Comment: Can anybody explains to me why I have been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony Imaging Edge Desktop was first released in December 2019

The oldest macOS supported is 10.13 (the newest is currently 10.15, no macOS 11 support yet)

No Mac is stuck on 10.12, so I'd suggest you update to High Sierra.